# scrollTop does not work with overflow:auto property in css

Tags: jquery, css

Apologize if you find this question repetitive, but I could not find the proper answer on StackOverflow.

I use the following properties in my css class:

```
.panel{
     background: rgba(203, 203, 210, 0.15);
     position: relative;
     float: right;
     ...
     overflow: auto;
 }
```

When I use `$('body').animate({scrollTop: 10}, 500);` JQuery function to scroll the page to top, it does not work. When I replace the auto value to something like 'visible' or 'inherit', it works. The structure of page requires the overflow property though.

Any idea?

Comment: Add some html and screenshot.

Comment: Which browser? And add more of your HTML... I can write a simple case which works fine with CSS position, float, and overflow has you've specified, so there's something else going on.

Comment: Please add the html/css/jquery needed to replicate the current behavior that isn't working.

Comment: Not only with jQuery, as long as overflow is auto or visible, dom properties scrollTop and scrollLeft are always 0 whatever are assigned. I can't find a scollTop solution to scrolling it while keeping overflow visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could overcome the issue with `overflow:auto` was increasing the height of the page temporary and reset the height to its original value, as follows:

```
$('.panel').css({"min-height":"200%"});
$('body').animate({scrollTop: 10}, 500);
$('.panel').css({"min-height":"100%"});
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this to your specifications without removing the overflow value, you can wrap the scrollable .panel in a wrapper and use that. I have taken your code and added my own in this code pen, the only difference being that the wrapper is added and the js adapted accordingly.

https://codepen.io/c0un7z3r0/pen/Emgdbr

```
$(".button").click(function(){
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
});
```

Scroll to the bottom to find a button that takes you back to the top, you'll note the css is the same as that posted in your example. I hope this helps.